# Sub caption of table produces large white gap

Tags: tables, spacing, subcaption, scrbook, gap

For tables I need a caption above, and sub captions beneath the table, to define all abbreviations used in the tables.

The solution I'm using so far results in a large white space after the table/ the tables' sub caption.
I want to emphasize that just the sub caption leads to this gap. Inserting the table without the sub caption shows a typical beautiful LaTeX table and text surrounding it normally.

Does anyone have an idea on how to reduce this space/ gap?

I append the code I'm using and an image so you can see the gap.

Thanks a lot for any help/ advise.

[image: Image showing the white space after a table with sub caption]

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

some text ...

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\caption
[table heading]
{more specific table heading.}
  % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \toprule
  some entry \\
  \midrule
  some other entry \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\\[0.35cm]%subcaption
\caption*{
explanations of entries
}%
\label{tab:cleaning_solutions}
\end{table}

some other text ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: If not automated solution presents itself, one can always perform a `\vspace{-<length>}` following a float.

Comment: As I see you like to have footnotes at table. In this case maybe use of  `threeparttable`  table could be handy.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I've tried the threeparttable but I don't like the style it uses. So I'll stick to my old way so far. The \vspace works nicely, even if it is kind of hard to implement. Someone has an idea of a more automates solution?

Comment: The example document does not compile, and therefore I cannot reproduce your problem, and therefore I'm unable to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that locally uses `\captionbelow` instead `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}% <- needed for \caption*

\newcommand\addcaptionbelow[1]{{%
  \let\caption\captionbelow
  \caption*{#1}%
}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
  \caption
    [table heading]
    {more specific table heading.}
  \begin{tabular}{p{.9\linewidth}}% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX
    \toprule
    some entry \\
    \midrule
    some other entry \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \addcaptionbelow{explanations of entries}
  \label{tab:cleaning_solutions}
\end{table}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]